# Error loading Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Model.TSqlModel in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dacpac

I am trying to create a dacpac model in code, see the snippet below. When I call the `LoadFromDacpac` function, I get following error:

**System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.Eventing.EventDescriptor' from assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'**

Any help appreciated in how to resolve this. Many thanks.

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions.dll'

$dacpacFilePath = 'C:\Users\dominic\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\DAC Packages\AdventureworksLT.dacpac'

$modelOptions = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Model.ModelLoadOptions

#Following call results in error: 
$model = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Model.TSqlModel]::LoadFromDacpac($dacpacFilePath, $modelOptions)
```

Comment: When you asked your question, you were told *"Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)."* Please follow the instructions when posting your questions, as otherwise you are likely to receive down and/or close votes; meaning your question is far less likely to be answered.

Comment: Try SQLPackage : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-extract?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @jdweng. I have used SQLPackage previously to deploy dacpacs, but in this instance, I need to instantiate the DAC model to subsequently query its properties (i.e. field names and types) to create custom .sql statements. And I'm mandated to use PS to do this.

Comment: For your second error, which of [these constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.model.tsqlmodel?view=sql-dacfx-162#constructors) are you trying to use? Because I agree with the error message you're getting which is that what you're using doesn't match any of them. Which leads to the first error - if you get the full exception, does that shed any light?

Comment: The is PS code on the link I provided.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. I managed to extract the inner exception and have updated the issue with this information (but I still haven't managed to fix it).